# How to find elements in DYNAMIC page using selenium - java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to selenium web-driver and i'm trying to make a simple login automation.
**Here is the link to the ebay login page:** https://signin.ebay.com/

**Here is the html code for the username input box:**

```html
<input size="40" maxlength="64" name="2045849967" id="2045849967" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Email or username" class="fld">
```

**Here is the html code for the password input box:**

```html
<input size="40" maxlength="64" name="955270437" id="955270437" type="password" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Password" class="fld">
```

**Here is my code trying to sendKeys into the username and password input boxes:**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("2045849967")).sendKeys("blabla@gmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("955270437")).sendKeys("somePassword");
```

The problem is that I can't find the elements by these ids since it's change every time the page is loaded/refreshed.
Please note that the all id is completely change.
What is my options to solve the problem?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I succeed to get into the username box by finding the 'register' element in the login page and clicking 'Tab', but now when i'm into the username box I don't know how can I 'sendKeys' into because I don't really have the username element.

**Here is the code:**

```html
WebElement regElement = driver.findElement(By.id("regTab"));
regElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

Now how can I continue from here ? 
I need to insert the username and then click 'Tab' again and insert password.
What is the options?

Comment: Try with css or xpath locators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these

```
By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Email or username']")
By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Password']")
```

Apparently, there are two matches for the email field and the first one is hidden which causes this to fail. You can still use these selectors, you'll just have to grab the 2nd match for the first locator.

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Email or username']")).get(1).sendKeys("abc");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Password']")).sendKeys("abc");
```

Comment: It doesn't work .. anything else maybe? or any idea why it doesn't work? because the placeholder is really not changing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem.

```html
        WebElement regElement = driver.findElement(By.id("regTab"));
  regElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
  WebElement currentElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
  currentElement.sendKeys("blabla@gmail.com");
  currentElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
  currentElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
  currentElement.sendKeys("somePassword");
  
  driver.findElement(By.id("sgnBt")).click();
```